# how to create input search word with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one `input` and one `ul` that has many `li` like this :

**input**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="searching friends ..." id="search-friends">
```

this is list of my friends:

```
<ul id="friend-list">
    <li class="on" id="1" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>Janatan</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="on" id="2" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>andy</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="3" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>Anna</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="4" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>fred</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="5" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>john</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="of" id="6" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name"> <span>cristian</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want when type any word hide `ul` and show me related **li** that is like typing name .....

Comment: I want help me about that

Comment: Okay. Use jQuery [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Have you looked into the jQuery UI autocomplete tool? It does exactly what you want and works perfectly...let me know if I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search-friends').on('keyup', function() {    
    $('.friend-name span').each(function(){
        if ($(this).html().indexOf($('#search-friends').val()) != -1 {
            //SHOW/HIGHLIGHT/OR WHATEVER THE li's you are looking for
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks my friend but I want when one by one letter enter in input this search in all spans in all lies and show me result

Comment: edited my answer so that on each keyup all the names in the span are checked  if they contain the string from the input

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of a tried and tested autocomplete plugin like `jQuery UI Autocomplete`, but in case you want a no-frills approach, you can try this:

```
var $list = $('#friend-list');

//Hide the list items initially
$list.find('li').hide();

$('#search-friends').on('keyup', function() {
    $list.find('li').hide();

    //Select only elements that contain the query string and show it
    $list.find('li:contains("' + this.value.toLowerCase() + '")').show();
});
```

Here's the working demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/tfMZg/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/tfMZg/4/)

Comment: my friend if my li's exist ANDY what I do?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get you, do you mean you want to check `case` - uppercase/lowercase as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-friends").keyup(function (){
        searchFriendsByPattern($("#search-friends").val());
    });
});

function searchFriendsByPattern(pattern){
    $("#friend-list").children("li").each(function () {
        var liText = $(this).find("span").text().toLowerCase();
        if (liText.indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) == -1){
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else{
           $(this).show();
        }
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc3e9/)